# How to combine 12 tables with some different and some same fields

Tags: oracle

Hi friends i am having problem in joining  tables in oracle my tables are shown bellow

**table1 looks like**

```
 id    Name    Jan
 7001  Deven   22 
 7002  Clause  55 
 7004  Monish  11 
 7010  Dipesh  55
 7070  Dipika  100
```

**table2 looks like**

```
  id      Name       Feb  
  7001    Deven      12 
  7002    Clause     15 
  7003    Nimesh     20 
  7004    Monish     21 
  7005    Ritesh     22
```

**table 3 looks like**

```
  id      Name       Mar  
  7001    Deven      122 
  7020    Chalse     155 
  7003    Nimesh     88 
  7033    Monica     217 
  7070    Dipika     180
```

like this i am having 12 tables from january to December hwo can i combine this and get out put like below:

```
  id      Name      Jan   Feb  Mar ...................... Dec
  7001    Deven     22    12   122
  7002    Clause    55    15   -   .......................-
  7003    Nimesh    -     20   88  .......................2
  7004    Monish    11    21   -   .......................-
  7005    Ritesh    -     22   -   .......................20
  7010    Dipesh    55    -    -   .......................-
  7020    Chalse    -     -    155 .......................-
  7033    Monica    -     -    217 .......................100
  7070    Dipika    100   -    -   .......................-
```

Comment: Do you have any table that contains **all ids**?

Comment: Why do you have 12 tables, one for each month, rather than a single "months" (or "bookings") table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for a GROUP BY without join (probably the most efficient since there is a single pass on each table -- the GROUP BY clause will de-dupe):

```
select id, name, max(jan) jan, max(feb) feb, /*...*/ max(dec) dec
  from (select id, name, jan jan, null feb, /*...*/ null dec
           from table1
         union all
         select id, name, null jan, feb feb, /*...*/ null dec
           from table2
         union all
         /*...*/
         select id, name, null jan, null feb, /*...*/ dec dec 
           from table12)
 group by id, name
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach below is to create a derived table that contains all ids and names, and then use that to join against each of your tables. Unlike `UNION ALL`, `UNION` removes the duplicates for us:

```
select a.id, a.name, t1.Jan, t2.Feb, t3.Mar
from (
    select id, name from table1 
    union
    select id, name from table2
    union
    select id, name from table3 
) a
left outer join table1 t1 on a.id = t1.id
left outer join table2 t2 on a.id = t2.id
left outer join table3 t3 on a.id = t3.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider making those all one table with columns: "id, Name, Month, Quantity" (and then even a year if you are going to span years).